# Rmarkdown presentation slide tickers

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using rmarkdown to make beamer presentations in RStudio. I would want to get slide tickers on the top of presentation. Dresden theme should support those tickers[Dresden](https://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/all/beamer-default-Dresden-0.png)
[image]

So is it possible to get those tickers by using rmarkdown? When I knit pdf I get presentation without slide tickers.

Example code:

````
---
title: "Example"
output: beamer_presentation
theme: Dresden
---

# R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

# Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

# Slide with R Code and Output

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

# Slide with Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `slide_level` option might be what you are looking for:

> The slide_level option defines the heading level that defines individual slides. By default this is the highest header level in the hierarchy that is followed immediately by content, and not another header, somewhere in the document. This default can be overridden by specifying an explicit slide_level
>   [documentation source](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/beamer_presentation_format.html)

For example with the `slide_level: 2`:

```
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 2
theme: Dresden
---
```

gives you the following output

[image]

However you need to provide a lower level of the heading for the slide title, e.g.

```
# R Markdown

## Description
This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting 
syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more 
details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that 
includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code 
chunks within the document.
```

**Edit** To get the output same as in the image you have attached, you section your presentation in the following way:

```
---
title: "Example"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 3
theme: Dresden
---
# Section 1
## Subsection 1
### Title A
### Title B
## Subsection 2
### Title A
## Subsection 3
### Title A
### Title B
### Title C
# Section 2
## Subsection 1
### Title A
### Title B
```

and the following presentation heading is generated:

[image]

Comment: Well that I can do but I am looking for solution to do exactly as in the question picture, I may have to modify the question to be more exact.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure if you are interested in this solution, but the header you have provided is easy to get - I have added content in the answer